# Integrate payment Gateway with rails

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, payment-gateway, payment

Right now we are owner of site. And we do have 2 types of users. One can organize events and another users can sponser that event. so what I actually need is that once sponsor will do payment to event organizer then entire payment will go in our account.

after verification from our side we will keep 20% of total payment in my account and remaining will goes into event organizer's account.

Any Payment gateway provide this kind of setting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use `gem 'stripe'`through easy to Integrate payment Gateway with rails

[Stripe Docs](https://github.com/stripe/stripe-ruby)